# Linux transfer parameter for function in DECLARE_WORK

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I try to programm a Event-Workqueue, but I meet some problems.

I use a Linux 2.6.36 Kernel. And the DECLARE_WORK function changed from 3 parameters to 2.

The question is, the old declaration was

```
 DECLARE_WORK  (struct work_struct name,  void (*func)(void *),  void *data);
```

And the new one is

```
 DECLARE_WORK  (struct work_struct name,  void (*func)(void *));
```

I think the void *data pointer was to give the func parameters. Is that right?
And how can I do that with the new version of DECLARE_WORK?

Thanks for the help

Peter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DECLARE_WORK` is primarily for static work items, where no instance data is needed. You want `INIT_WORK`. Use this to initialize a `work_struct` that is a member of another structure (of your choosing), then use `container_of` in the callback to get the pointer to the containing structure. This `container_of` pattern is extremely common in the Linux kernel, so it's a good idea to get familiar with it!

You can see an example of this with `wl1271_netstack_work` - take a look at the [initialization point](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5.3/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/main.c#L5102) and [the callback](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5.3/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/main.c#L518).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.                                              So the answer of the Question `I think the void *data pointer was to give the func parameters. Is that right?` is NO?

Comment: It was used for that, but it's not really necessary with `container_of`, so I guess it was removed to save memory.