# passing/sharing the data using workQueue in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Please can anyone help me in understanding "Passing data(shared or private)" to workQueue ?

## 1: Declare a call back/work handler

```
static void sample_work_fn(struct work_struct *Wq)
{
...........
...........
}
```

## 2:  fill in a work_struct structure (statically)

```
static DECLARE_WORK(sample_work, sample_work_fn);
```

## 3: Schedule a workqueue

```
static void samp_sysrq(int arg)
{
        schedule_work(sample_work);
}
```

Here if I need to pass/share data using my work queue, how is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Linux Work Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937245/how-to-use-linux-work-queue)

Comment: Sanumala, welcome to Stack Overflow. As my previous comment suggests, this question has already been answered in another post. Please see the link in the above comment. This site prefers to have as few duplicate questions as possible so it is likely this thread will be closed. Please do not take offense to this and treat it as a learning experience. Again, welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Benjamin,

I found the information in "[Linux transfer parameter for function in DECLARE_WORK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153797/linux-transfer-parameter-for-function-in-declare-work)" is really straight forward and it really Helped me to understand. this links says

DECLARE_WORK is primarily for static work items, where no instance data is needed. You want INIT_WORK. Use this to initialize a work_struct that is a member of another structure (of your choosing), then use container_of in the callback to get the pointer to the containing structure. This container_of pattern is extremely common in the Linux kernel, so it's a good idea to get familiar with it!